# How to use sendmail to send to remote smtp postfix relay

Tags: sendmail

I have a machine I don't want postfix running on and am using sendmail.  I modified /etc/mail/sendmail.mc to have this line(hoping it would send mail through that postfix server)...

```
 define(`SMART_HOST', `postfixhost.yyyy.com')dnl
```

and ran make to regen the sendmail.cf file and checked it and it looks good.  I then sendmail(using the same exact command and same email I use on my relay proxy host which already works good).

I see this error in the /var/log/maillog of my sendmail host

```
Jan  4 06:59:22 b1 sendmail[20508]: r04DxMkr020508: from=root, size=101, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201301041359.r04DxMkr020508@sendmailhost.yyyy.com>, relay=root@localhost
Jan  4 06:59:22 b1 sendmail[20508]: r04DxMkr020508: to=dean.hiller@yyyy.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30101, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

Why is it using 127.0.0.1 to send email still?

Any ideas?
thanks,
Dean

Comment: Consider not using sendmail either; instead, install a minimalistic nullclient such as ssmtp or msmtp, and set the smarthost there. You don't run any risk of exposing mail services unintentionally with a nullclient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On you machine there are two sendmail processes running. One is using the `submit.cf` configuration file and it is the one that tries to hand locally generated mail (like from `/bin/mail`) to 127.0.0.1. You generally need not bother with `submit.{mc,cf}`.

Now on 127.0.0.1 there is also another sendmail process running, the one reading the configuration from `sendmail.cf`. Each time you change `sendmail.mc` you need to regenerate `sendmail.cf` and restart sendmail afterwards.